# Cakephp 2.x if, else

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2

Tenho um projeto em Cakephp 2.x, com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Planos', array('url' => 'addPlanos')); 

foreach($ListarPlanos as $indice => $AdicionarPlanos): 

foreach($totalPlanosAlunos as $contador => $planos): 

if($AdicionarPlanos['Planos']['status'] == 0) :

if($AdicionarPlanos['Planos']['id'] !== $planos['id']):

echo $AdicionarPlanos['Planos']['id'] ;

endif ;

endif ;
endforeach ;
endforeach ;
```

Nele não adiciona o plano que o aluno não possuem, ou seja o `!=` não funciona.

Comment: E a sua dúvida é?

Comment: Não adiciona no banco ou não gera o formulário?